# Retrieving variables from another class - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to retrieve an `NSString` type variable from my class `PYTimelineViewController` inside my class `rippleMake`.

Here what I am doing:

in my `rippleMake.m`

```
    /* SET OBJECT */
    PYTimelineViewController *getRippleForVideo = [[PYTimelineViewController alloc] init];
    /* ESTABLISH THE RIPPLE IT VIDEO FOR CHALLENGE VIDEO */
    NSString *videoFor = [getRippleForVideo getchallengeForVideo];
    NSLog(@"%@",videoFor);
```

When this runs, `videoFor` returns `null`.

in my `PYTimelineViewController.h`

```
@interface PYTimelineViewController : UITableViewController//<MWPhotoBrowserDelegate>

...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *challengeForVideo;
-(NSString *)getchallengeForVideo;
- (void)setchallengeForVideo:(NSString*)challengeforVideo;
@end
```

in my `PYTimelineViewController.m`

```
-(IBAction)openRippleIt:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSInteger rowOfTheCell = (indexPath.row + 1000); // ADD 1000 to get away from effecting other code
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:rowOfTheCell];

    NSString *btnTitle = [button currentTitle];
    [self setchallengeForVideo:btnTitle];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self getchallengeForVideo]); <--- This outputs exactly what I need.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveTorippleIt" sender:self];
}
```

The `.m` getters and setters:

```
-(void) setchallengeForVideo:(NSString *)challengeforVideo
{
    _challengeForVideo = challengeforVideo;
}
-(NSString *) getchallengeForVideo
{
    return _challengeForVideo;
}
```

This is of coarse pushing the user to the new `ViewController` but that shouldnt be an issue.

Not sure why I am unable to retrieve the value because everything seems to be properly configured.  Especially my getters and setters.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: When is called `openRippleIt` that set `challengeForVideo`?

Comment: Please note that getters and setters are generated for you for properties. You can completely delete the getchallengeForVideo and setchallengeForVideo: methods.

Comment: @CrimsonChris is on the right track, you need to somehow reference the previous `PYTimelineViewController` not create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve an object from the view controller, you could simply send the object to your class.

When you instantiate `PYTimelineViewController` in `rippleMake.m`, this one is completely new so you loose the wanted object's reference.

Also, you don't need to implement a getter or setter **if your only goal at that point** is to retrieve var's value.
The `@property` key creates getter/setter for you.

Pass object to your view by adding a **public property** in this one:

```
// RippleMake.h
// e.g
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *foo
```

When you instantiate your class in the view controller, be sure to pass the property:

```
// ViewController.m
// e.g
RippleMake *ripple = ....
ripple.foo = foo;
...
```

To pass objects to view controller to another, you must just do the same thing but in  `prepareForSegue:sender` method, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22867976/1745596

Answer (score 2):

`[[PYTimelineViewController alloc] init]` creates a new PYTimelineViewController and doesn't give an existing one.

[Some code not executing in a method called from another ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849894/some-code-not-executing-in-a-method-called-from-another-viewcontroller/22854854#22854854)

Answer (score 1):

A few other comments...

You don't need getters and setters if you're using Xcode >= 4.4.  They are automatically created by the compiler in response to the `@property`.

Idiomatic Objective-C doesn't use the "get" prefix on properties.

"Copy" is typically the correct property attribute to use for strings, since they can be mutable.

Your header should look like this:

```
@interface PYTimelineViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *challengeForVideo;
@end
```

Usage should look like this:

```
PYTimelineViewController *vc = [[PYTimelineViewController alloc] init];
[vc setChallengeForVideo:@"some text"];
NSLog(@"%@", [vc challengeForVideo]);
```

For bonus points, use the dot syntax instead:

```
PYTimelineViewController *vc = [[PYTimelineViewController alloc] init];
vc.challengeForVideo = @"some text";
NSLog(@"%@", vc.challengeForVideo);
```